# derived class problem  using interface

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-7

[image]I have a interface

```
interface Dot
{    
    // protected Random r = new Random();
    void createdot(Rectangle clientrectangle, Control.ControlCollection Controls);
}
```

and I use this interface as a base class for my derived classes as stated

```
public class BlueDot : Dot 
{
    public  List<Label> bluedot = new List<Label>();
    Random r = new Random();

    public  void  createdot(Rectangle ClientRectangle, Control.ControlCollection Controls)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var temp = new Label();

            temp.Location = new Point(r.Next(ClientRectangle.Right - 10), r.Next(ClientRectangle.Bottom - 20));
            temp.Text = "?";
            temp.Width = 10;
            temp.Height = 10;
            temp.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            temp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            Controls.Add(temp);
            temp.Visible = true;
            temp.Show();
            bluedot.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RedDot:Dot
{
    public List<Label> reddot = new List<Label>();
    Random r = new Random();

    public   void  createdot(Rectangle Clientrectangle,Control.ControlCollection Controls)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
        {
            var temp2 = new Label();

            temp2.Location = new Point(r.Next(Clientrectangle.Right - 10), r.Next(Clientrectangle.Bottom - 20));
            temp2.Text = "?";
            temp2.Width = 10;
            temp2.Height = 10;
            temp2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            temp2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            Controls.Add(temp2);
            temp2.Show();
            reddot.Add(temp2);
        }
    }
```

and they are called here

```
BlueDot bdot = new BlueDot();
        RedDot rdot = new RedDot();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Activate();
    bdot.createdot(this.ClientRectangle,this.Controls);
    rdot.createdot(this.ClientRectangle, this.Controls);       
}
```

Why is it that I keep getting only 5 red dots even if the loop performs 10 iterations?

here is the sample output https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2372861522202&set=a.1600508493859.85328.1270463960&type=1 , i just cant figure out what happened to the other 5 red dots, it should be 10 red dots....

Comment: Please format your questions properly; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Its normal to prefix interface names with "I" to indicate that they are an interface, so for example you would normally use the name `IDot` instead of `Dot` in the above.

Comment: how's bdot and rdot initialized?

Comment: Are your red dots being drawn over the top of your other dots?

Comment: @justin yeah , but why is it that my red dot only is 5? it should be 10

Comment: have you tried to look at the values returned by r.Next(...) my guess is that the dot are drawn ontop of each other. you should not create a new Random object but reuse it

Comment: You really ought to create a generic dot class and pass in the colour. Your design is all wrong.

Comment: its not the design , its the output im worried about, please help me...

Comment: did you checked by debugging...why the loop terminates after 5 iterations?

Comment: it only terminates on the last iteration, that said, i dont know what to do with a problem like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inheritance problem here. The problem is the random number generator.

Try this line in your code:

```
temp2.Location = new Point(10 * z, 10 * z);
```

Replacing

```
temp2.Location = new Point(r.Next(Clientrectangle.Right - 10), r.Next(Clientrectangle.Bottom - 20));
```

You'll see your 5 blue "?"-labels and your 10 red "?"-labels

To solve the problem of the weak random number generator try **seeding** your random number generator. Example:

```
Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Comment: i see my 10 red dots now... but... its positioned diagonally , i need it to be scattered ...

Comment: @jeo, The point was to demonstrate that there is NO problem with the inheritance. Put back your original line, then replace the line that creates the random number generator with the one I gave you in my answer.

Comment: this was a great help.. but i have another question regarding pacman eating these labels... can i just edit the question again?

Comment: Glad that I could help. I would just ask another question and mention (and link) this one as a reference/background/context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3258/discussion-between-tzup-and-jeo)

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure, but why aren't you making your temp2 visible ????

temp2.Visible=true

If this dowsn't work can you provide a screen shot of both your output. Sometimes due to the size of the window one dot may reside over another. I mean they actually overlap. Seeing your output may help to sort out your problem

Comment: how to post the image/screenshot? ??

Comment: that isnt the matter , its the output, i cant figure out whats wrong with the output

Comment: got the picture now sir. take a look on the discription

Comment: i don't know about anyone else but i can't see that picture (via the facebook link). is there anywhere else (public) you can post it?

Comment: i've tried to load the pic in the facebook link from my work pc and my phone - both say 'this content is currently unavailable'

Comment: @jeo I too can't see the image. `Facebook` is blocked on my network. Could you please upload the image here.

Comment: When creating a new Label, it has its Visible property set to True by default.